# MySQL partition and unique key

Tags: mysql, partitioning

We are having a table like this to save login tokens per user sessions. This table was not partitioned earlier but now we decided to partition it to improve performance as it contains over a few millions rows.

```
CREATE TABLE `tokens` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `session` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `token` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `usersession` (`uid`,`session`),
  KEY `uid` (`uid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 PARTITION BY HASH(id) PARTITIONS 101;
```

We plan to partition based on '***id***' as it's primarily used for "***select***" queries and hence can effectively perform pruning.

However the problem is we maintain unique index of ***(uid, session)*** and partition requires participating column to be part of unique index. Now in this case unique index of ***(id, uid, session)*** doesn't make sense (will always be unique).

is there anyway to get around this issue without manually checking (uid, session).

Comment: You are screwed. You will have to index uid and session separetly and thus made them non UNIQUE. I am not sure that partitionning is the right way to go in your case. "over a few millions rows" isnt that much and doesnt require partionning to me. There will be another con if you make the partionning: there's no "_global index_" functionnality on mysql partitions...

Comment: ....Your partitions therefore act as separate tables. It means that if you want to search for a specific uid (it should happen since you have separate index on that column), mysql will have to check all indexes of all partitions to return the results, which might afftect the performances worstly as it is today.

Comment: We don't need to search uid, we only need to find uid from the token. As I mentioned, id is used for select. There are around 40M rows which demanded parititioning.

Comment: Are you considering partitioning because it seems liike the right thing to do? Or in response to a particular problem?

Comment: When you have unique keys, **every `INSERT` and `UPDATE` operation is also a search operation.**

Answer (score 2):

Presumably your unique `uid,sessionkey` index enforces some business rule for you.

Do you rely on DBMS enforcement of that rule? Do you use `INSERT .... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...` statements, or use error handlers, or some such thing, to handle this uniqueness?  Or is it there just for good measure?

If you rely on that unique index, **partitioning this table on `id` will not work.** Fugeddaboudit.

If you can delete that index, or delete its unique constraint, you may be able to proceed with partitioning. But partitioning isn't generally suitable for tables with multiple unique keys.

A 40M-row table is ordinarily not large enough to be a good candidate for partitioning. If you're having performance problems you should investigate improving your indexing instead.

**Edit**: If you have modern hardware (multi-terabyte storage, plenty of RAM) and well-chosen indexes, partitioning is (I believe) more trouble that it's worth. It's definitely a lot of trouble for tables with fewer than about  10**9 rows. When your autoincrementing `id` values *must* be `BIGINT` rather than `INT` data types (because int.MaxValue isn't big enough), that's when partitioning starts to be worth considering.

It's most effective when all queries filter based on the partitioning key.  Filtering on other criteria without the partitioning key is slow.

**Pro tip:** The old saying about regular expressions also applies to partititions.  If you solve a problem with partitioning, now you have two problems.

Comment: Thanks, could you please elaborate on "40M-row table is ordinarily not large enough to be a good candidate for partitioning". I thought this size could indeed benefit from partitioning. But if it's not the case, what would be ideal size when you want to partition your tables.

Comment: Partitioning was first rolled out about nine years ago. That's six cycles of Moore's law ago. In each 18-month cycle the available size of disk (and SSD) storage has appropximately doubled for the same cost.

Answer (score 2):

- Don't use partitioning.  It won't speed up this kind of table.
- I have yet to see a case of `BY HASH` that speeds up a system.
- It is almost never useful to partition on the `PRIMARY KEY`.
- In general, don't have an `AUTO_INCREMENT` id when you have a perfectly good "natural" PK -- `(uid, session)`.  Or should it be `(toke n)`?
- Don't have one index being the first part of another: `(uid)` is redundant, given `(uid, session)`.
- Consider using utf8mb4 if you expect to have Emoji or Chinese.  On the other hand, if `token` is, say, base64, then make it `ascii` or something.

So, I think this will work significantly better (smaller, faster, etc):

```
CREATE TABLE `tokens` (
  `uid` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `session` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `token` VARBINARY(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (token),
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Which of these do you search by?

```
WHERE token = ...
WHERE uid = ... AND session = ...
```

One drawback is that I got rid of `id`; if `id` is needed by other tables, then a change is needed there.